# Regular expression search file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file and I want to serach a specific word on it  in arabic

```
lines = 0
with io.open('path.csv','r',encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f :
     lines= lines+1
     r=re.search(r'\w''[\u0627\u0644\u0631\u064A\u0627\u0636]',f)
     print (line,r)     
f.close()
```

I want to print the line with the word is like extracting the row that contain my word on to new csv file

I get this error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path.py", line 11, in <module>
    r=re.search(r'\w''[\u0627\u0644\u0631\u064A\u0627\u0636]',f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: You can't search a file (`f`)

Comment: Change `r=re.search(r'\w''[\u0627\u0644\u0631\u064A\u0627\u0636]',f)` to `r=re.search(r'\w''[\u0627\u0644\u0631\u064A\u0627\u0636]',line)`

Comment: Why don't you parse the text in the CSV file into arrays with the `csv` module? Then you could just do `if pattern in item` for each item in each `csv` row, which is both faster and easier to write/read/maintain. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I didn't know about it

Answer (score 0):

A few comments here:

- The re.search should look for the match within "line" i.e. the current line of the file
- I assume you're wanting to print the line number (lines) and the match, not the full string of the line
- There's no need to say f.close() if you opened it using a "with" context manager
- You said you want to match a word. Putting the Arabic characters inside the square brackets will match based on any one character, not the full word. Remove the square brackets
- Do you really need the \w?

How's this:

```
import io
import re

lines = 0
with io.open('path.csv','r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f :
        lines += 1
        r = re.search('\u0627\u0644\u0631\u064A\u0627\u0636', line)
        if r:
            print (lines, r)
```

Comment: thats work for me thank you but now I want to save it to csv file also the result I mean how I can do that ?

Comment: A crude but effective way would be
 
    if r:
        print ("{},{}".format(lines, r[0]))